# Vuetifyjs error Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Am using vuetify to build a template but am getting an error

```
unknown custom element dashboard did you register the component correctly?
```

This is my code:

```
In the main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 import {routes} from './routes';

  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  Vue.use(Vuetify)

 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

In my App.vue

```
<template>
  <dashboard></dashboard>

 </template>
<script>
 import Dashbaord from './components/dashboard/Dashboard.vue';
   export default {
  name: "appinit",
  components: {
   "dashboard":Dashboard
  }
}
```

And here is my dashboard

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <left-drawer></left-drawer>
    <toolbar></toolbar> <!-- Dashboard Toolbar-->
    <main>
      <v-container fluid>
        ..info are
        </v-slide-y-transition>
      </v-container>
    </main>
  <right-drawer></right-drawer>
  <footer-area></footer-area>
</v-app>
</template>

  <script>
  imports  ......

 export default {
   components: {
    Toolbar, RightDrawer,LeftDrawer,FooterArea
   }
 }
```

What could be wrong as i have just separated the initial vuefy installation component into different component sections

The code is available at github on [This link](https://github.com/lamatuts/dashboard.git)

What could be wrong?

Comment: I cant see where you register your dashboard component. Have a look at their https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration

Comment: i have registered dashboard as a local component in the AppVue components, Check the components:{} area

Comment: as specified here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few issues in your code.

1. You have to close  tag in App.vue
2. Fix typo App.vue line 6 "Dashboard"
3. Remove footer-area from Dashboard.Vue (you don't have that component, yet ;) )