# SimulatedGreg Electron-Vue-Vuetify Error message: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, vuetify.js

First, let me say thank you for helping with my problem. I started struggling with this problem this morning at about 9 am, it's now 3 pm and I am still not able to figure out what if anything will fix this issue. I lost count of the number of youtube videos I watched in an attempt to understand the underlying principles that I might have missed.

Here are all of the other StackOverflow question-answer pairs that I have also looked at and attempted (sometimes multiple times & in combination even) all without luck:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-unknown-custom-element-v-card/43018

[<v-card> - did you register the component correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146259/v-card-did-you-register-the-component-correctly)

["[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: ..." Error, when using vuetify UI components with the vue-cli-plugin-vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216190/vue-warn-unknown-custom-element-error-when-using-vuetify-ui-component)

[Vuetifyjs error Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279449/vuetifyjs-error-unknown-custom-element-did-you-register-the-component-correctly)

https://github.com/SeregPie/VuetifyImageInput/issues/3

https://michaelnthiessen.com/solve-unknown-custom-element-vue/

[Vue/Vuetify - Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298751/vue-vuetify-unknown-custom-element-v-app-did-you-register-the-component-c)

[Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388315/unknown-custom-element-v-app-did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for)

At this point I have basically given up on finding a solution for Vuetify, and if I still cannot find a solution by Monday, then I will abandon Vuetify completely and move on to another framework such as VueBootstrap.

Problem Setup:
I am just trying to learn Electron-Vue-Vuetify by using project-based learning. I decided to start by building a simple calculator application just so I can learn how to create components and wire them together with code and perhaps learn how to do SASS/CSS styling/themes as well.

I created a boiler-plate application using the SimulatedGreg template on GitHub:
https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

I validated the application is running.
Then I followed the steps to NPM install Vuetify. I noticed that the vuetify installer modified the App.vue file in the root folder but not the App.vue in the renderer folder. So I moved that around, and I also noticed that the Vuetify installer created a new components folder also at the root of the src folder, so I moved that HelloWorld.vue component into the src/renderer/components folder. I made a few other minor changes to make sure I did the best I could to wire it up. Validated that the Vuetify plugin was installed and saved in the Dev-dependencies in the package.json, and a few other odds and ends.

Finally, I was able to get where the application would load but all the styling was wrong. Now it's just a flat text rendered to the DOM with no styling at all. I get a bunch of errors in the developer tools:

Here is the full error log: (Sorry a bit long I know, I tried to remove the long redundant bits)

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js?a026:628
createElm @ vue.esm.js?a026:5949
patch @ vue.esm.js?a026:6488
Vue._update @ vue.esm.js?a026:3954
updateComponent @ vue.esm.js?a026:4075
get @ vue.esm.js?a026:4488
Watcher @ vue.esm.js?a026:4477
mountComponent @ vue.esm.js?a026:4082
Vue.$mount @ vue.esm.js?a026:9063
Vue.$mount @ vue.esm.js?a026:11974
init @ vue.esm.js?a026:3127
createComponent @ vue.esm.js?a026:5989
createElm @ vue.esm.js?a026:5936
patch @ vue.esm.js?a026:6527
Vue._update @ vue.esm.js?a026:3954
updateComponent @ vue.esm.js?a026:4075
get @ vue.esm.js?a026:4488
Watcher @ vue.esm.js?a026:4477
mountComponent @ vue.esm.js?a026:4082
Vue.$mount @ vue.esm.js?a026:9063
Vue.$mount @ vue.esm.js?a026:11974
(anonymous) @ main.js?cebd:13
./src/renderer/main.js @ renderer.js:1351
__webpack_require__ @ renderer.js:791
fn @ renderer.js:102
1 @ renderer.js:1423
__webpack_require__ @ renderer.js:791
(anonymous) @ renderer.js:858
(anonymous) @ renderer.js:861
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app-bar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
2vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-img> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-spacer> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-btn> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-icon> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-content> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
       <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-container> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-col> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-img> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
2vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-col> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-col> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-col> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
....
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/renderer/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <App> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Some of the Vuetify users might be also on the Vuetify Facebook page. I did re-post my question there, just hoping to get any kind of help!

Some other things I tried which you might see in the code repo linked below:

In the main.js file I tried to modify the code in the following way....see the commented code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
// import '../plugins/vuetify' <--Attempted to add this....causes the application to not load anything!
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
```

Also in the main.js:

```
new Vue({
  components: { App },
  router,
  // vuetify: Vuetify, <--Also attempted to add this here....same issue as above, not loads at all.
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

I posted the code to a sandbox repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/SethEden/EVJS-Calculator

Feel free to clone it and see if you can help me figure out what it is that I have not done correctly or what I am missing? I'm sure it is something super silly, but hopefully, it will help someone else overcome similar or related issues. Again my main goal here is to learn! So if you have any additional information you can describe why a change is important that would help me learn more!!

And perhaps the answer to this question is something answered in one of those other questions, but perhaps I just didn't understand those answers fully enough to implement it in my own circumstance. In any case, I hope it benefits someone else!

Thank you again!!
Cheers & have a great weekend!
~Seth

**UPDATE:**

First setup, followed this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@bromix/electron-application-with-vue-js-and-vuetify-f2a1f9c749b8

npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create electron-app
vue add vuetify
vue add electron-builder

Result: Everything for Vue, Electron & Vuetify was working perfectly, but the folder structure was not correct to scale as an enterprise application.
Default folder structure:
ProjectName

- src
  --- main.js

This is what the folder structure should be:
ProjectName

- src
  --- Application
  ------ ProjectName
  --------- main.js

This way we can have a framework folder and everything will be contained within the src project root folder.

All files in the src path were moved into the new folder structure path: @/src/Application/ProjectName/.

Result: Build is completely broken.

Found this blog article:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/03/18/vue-cli-3-rename-src-folder/

And this article:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/03/11/vue-cli-3-full-stack/

And this GitHub bug report:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1134

After implementing these fixes, the build is still broken, additional searching and I found this:

https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#webpack-configuration

After implementing this fix and a few other obvious changes to various paths in the code files and package.json main entry-point,
the build is now working, but the application gives an error on load and the Vue fails to render.

Error message:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
utils.js?e375:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined
    at getPath (utils.js?e375:21)
    at getIDMapPath (index.js?b206:29)
    at eval (index.js?b206:32)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:1117)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (background.js?e28f:1)
    at Module../src/Application/electronVueJS-App/background.js (app.js:949)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
```

Looking up the utils.js?e375:21 at the following path:
C:\electronVueJS-App\node_modules\electron-devtools-installer\dist\utils.js

The code for the failure is:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.changePermissions = exports.downloadFile = exports.getPath = void 0;

var _electron = require("electron");

var _fs = _interopRequireDefault(require("fs"));

var _path = _interopRequireDefault(require("path"));

var _https = _interopRequireDefault(require("https"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }

var getPath = function getPath() {
  var savePath = _electron.app.getPath('userData'); // <-------------------- HERE
```

Attempted to modify the above code like so, to be able to see what exactly is failing:

```
var getPath = function getPath() {
    console.log('_electron is: ' + JSON.stringify(_electron));
    console.log('_electron is: ', _electron);
    var savePath = _electron.app.getPath('userData'); // <-------------------- HERE
```

Now the build fails to finish the build process, so attempting something else:
rather than:

```
var _electron = require("electron");
```

I'm going to do this:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const app = remote.app;
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

Then I will attempt:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
console.log('remote electron is: ", remote);
const app = remote.app;
console.log('remote app is: ', app);
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

and finally:

```
var getPath = function getPath() {
var savePath = app.getPath('userData');
```

Another build-time error:

```
[Window Title]
Error

[Main Instruction]
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

[Content]
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/utils.js?:11:20)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/utils.js (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:166:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/downloadChromeExtension.js?:16:14)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/downloadChromeExtension.js (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:142:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/index.js?:16:55)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/index.js (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:154:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\electronVueJS-App\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/Application/electronVueJS-App/background.js?:6:85)
```

That error is now happening on this line:

```
const electApp = remote.app;
```

So clearly that didn't work.

Reverting the code just to be safe, since that was the closest to getting a running application.

Error is now:

```
utils.js?e375:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined
    at getPath (utils.js?e375:19)
    at getIDMapPath (index.js?b206:29)
    at eval (index.js?b206:32)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-devtools-installer/dist/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:1117)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (background.js?e28f:1)
    at Module../src/Application/electronVueJS-App/background.js (app.js:949)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
```

Attempted to enable Chrome logging via the Electron logging argument:
"electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve --enable-logging",

This poped some additional windows but no additional information was displayed.

Further investigation with Sean Alexander Free on the VueJS Developers Facebook page discovered the following:
Interestingly, the problem is in the electron-dev-tools-installer node module's index.js on line 18:
var _utils = require("./utils");

The relative path isn't being found because the current directory is electron's renderer path.

Adding console.log(__dirname) after the require shows:
D:\workspace\electronVueJS-App\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer

Which of course is not the correct path to pull in a resource from a node_modules folder via a relative path.

Seems like this is an issue with the installer module itself, but I would assume some webpack trickery could get around this.

My response 
Ahhh I see what you are saying. So it seems somewhere in the Electron-dev-tools-installer internal code,
a developer reused the init-main path as the same path to base where to go and get the resources to load....
pretty typical programming technique to use since it seems they never planned to allow the system folder structure to
scale for custom enterprise solutions. (E.G. Client-Server).
Further I would make a bet that this wouldn't be the last of the problems I would run into....
and it certainly hasn't been the first.
I will revert back to the default installation and investigate ways to turn the background.js & main.js files
into a wrapper/call-forwarder and try to make it work that way.

Final WORKING Repo of the template is: (I will leave this up for others)
https://github.com/SethEden/electronVueJS-Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally new to Electron, meanwhile I found out that [Github reply](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/983#issuecomment-587346495) and tried it.
It's perfectly working (I've added a button on the top left to kinda test it).

[image]

Maybe not using the whole Electron boilerplate but it get's you with Electron + Vue + Vuetify ready. :)

I guess this [answer](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/725#issuecomment-433509217) may help you debug the whole boilerplate and make it work but it requires some webpack config knowledge.

Not sure if it's worth a time investment nor the struggle but since it's pointed out by several people, it may actually work. ^^

~~
Oh and I'm not an expert but you may maybe ask people on the [Vue Discord](https://discord.com/invite/HBherRA) if you want to debug your current configuration instead of my solution.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer! This seriously put me in the right direction, and ultimately I did end-up abandoning my idea of moving the main.js & background.js files into a sub-folder after much problems and difficulties. I will add all the things I attempted to solve this problem including reference links from my Dev-Journal as part of an update to the question in the hopes that it will help the next person who stumbles across a similar set of problems and/or has a similar goal. I really learned a lot by going through this effort!! :-D